# how to make a Matplotlib 3D plot bigger

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this piece of code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(data.FAC1_1, data.FAC2_1, data.FAC3_1, c='r', marker='o')

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

everything works perfectly fine. The only issue is that the scatter plot that comes out is really tiny. Is there a ay to make it bigger? I looked at the documentation but I wasn't able to find it.

Comment: see the first argument in the documentation here: http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make the figure itself bigger using figsize:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
```

To make the markers from the scatter plot bigger use `s`:

```
ax.scatter(data.FAC1_1, data.FAC2_1, data.FAC3_1, s=500, c='r', marker='o')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enlarge the 3D Scatter inside the figure

```
fig.subplots_adjust(top=1.1, bottom=-.1)
```